# Restlet Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven, restlet

Does anyone know what the RESTLET maven dependencies are?

None of the entries on the site work.  I had to end up installing jars to make it work.

Comment: They might not upload artifacts into repo1. Have you tried adding their repository to your POM as per: http://www.restlet.org/downloads/maven ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

add this repo:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.restlet.talend.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then include dependencies with your version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Use:

```
<properties>
    <restlet.version>2.0.14</restlet.version>
</properties>
```

to define restlet version or just put whichever version you like. Hope it helps!

Comment: I still have the missing artifact exception, even when I declare the repo in my pom.xml.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, and it didn't fix. Also ended up not using the maven dependencies and embedding the .jar files. I should mention that I also did cleaning, used Eclipse m2e and the command line and that I'm working in a Windows VM in parallels, if that explains anything more. Also I could easily access the webresources that Maven should have found from my browser, and all other artifacts were found and downloaded without problems. I guess this is a rare issue, but it has hit me and there was no fix.

Comment: FYI: After a Windows update and restart, everything just worked. I guess this is a bug in Maven that is hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the maven dependencies are not downloaded automatically. You have to force it using mvn compile.

Here is a reference to sample restful service that uses following dependencies :

http://topjavatutorial.com/frameworks/spring/spring-rest/standalone-restful-service-using-restlet-framework/

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the given mirrors in [this](http://dev.mygrid.org.uk/wiki/display/developer/Maven+repository)

**These mirrors are up to date so no need to worry about the versions and so on..**

Edit `settings.xml` in maven installation location to add mirrors.

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
     <mirror>
       <id>mygrid-restlet</id>
       <url>http://www.mygrid.org.uk/maven/restlet/maven.restlet.org</url>
       <mirrorOf>maven-restlet</mirrorOf>
     </mirror>
  </mirrors>
 </settings>
```

assuming that the POMs using the original repository uses:

```
<repository>
   <id>maven-restlet</id>
   <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
   <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.softlayer.api/softlayer-api-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.softlayer.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>softlayer-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```