# How can I get Restlet via Maven when I am behind a proxy?

Tags: maven, proxy, restlet

I tried their official sample pom at [here](http://restlet.com/downloads/current/) and got the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.example:myproject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failed to collect dependencies at org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:ja
>   r:2.3.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:jar:2.3.4: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:pom:2.3.4 from/to maven-restlet
>   (http://maven.restlet.com ): Not authorized ,
>   ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

Some investigation I have done:

1. I am not using a company mirror. I used to use but to debug this I disabled it, because our company mirror does not have this.
2. Non-Restlet components works fine with the proxy configuration I put in settings.xml. I am trying Camel examples btw.
3. Non-Restlet components will get a similar error if I use a incorrect password for the proxy.
4. I tried a mirror mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173761/restlet-maven-dependencies) and it does not work.

So it seems restlet specific, but I have run out of ideas.

Comment: As far as I can notice, I see no requests with 401 or 403 response in the request's log of the "maven server". it seems that the request did even not reach the server.

Comment: How did you configure the link to the Restlet maven repository? How did you configure the proxy in the Maven settings?

Comment: Hi @ThierryBoileau, I downloaded the pom file from [here](http://restlet.com/downloads/pom-download/) on the official website. Suddenly, it works now. I believe it is because it has been synced to our intrenal repository, because all jars are downloaded from our nexus. I cannot confirm, but I doubt that the proxy does not really proxy to outside repositories.