# Error when building branch 2.3: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ranger:ranger-solr-plugin:jar

Tags: apache-ranger

I'm trying to build the branch `ranger-2.3` with the maven command `mvn clean compile package install -DskipJSTests`. The command failed when building `SOLR Security Plugin` with the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ranger-solr-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ranger:ranger-solr-plugin:jar:2.3.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:7.7.1 -> org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0: Could not transfer artifact org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:pom:2.3.0 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [maven-restlet (http://maven.restlet.org, default, releases+snapshots), apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, disabled)] -> [Help 1]
```

I'm using `maven 3.8` with `openjdk8`. I'm also having the same problem with `Release 2.2.0`.

Could someone help me take a look at what I missed? Also, is there a place where I can download the prepackaged jars, instead of me building from the source code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `solr` is not able to pull `org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:pom:2.3.0`. Adding below repository fixed the issue for me;

```
    <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.restlet.talend.com/</url>
    </repository>
```

You can find more details here [Restlet Maven Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173761/restlet-maven-dependencies).